# What is the reputation point structure of Stack Overflow? Is it secret?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

(Or is it a service?)

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It is not a secret.

Comment: @Oded: shh! We don't want too many people knowing about the FAQ.

Comment: -1 Because you've already had one question migrated to meta before.

Comment: Removed my -1 again because his first question was unjustly migrated. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56716/what-is-an-openid-closed

Comment: @Pekka - Whoops. Well spotted! My vote is locked in now anyway.

Comment: Did this remind anyone else of the In-N-Out "secret menu"?

Answer (score 3):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> What is reputation?
>
> Reputation is completely optional.
>   Normal use of Stack Overflow — that
>   is, asking and answering questions —
>   does not require any reputation
>   whatsoever.
>
> Stack Overflow is run by you! To help
>   us run the site, you'll need to earn
>   some reputation first. Reputation is a
>   (very) rough measurement of how much
>   the community trusts you. Reputation
>   is never given, it is earned by
>   convincing fellow users that you know
>   what you're talking about.
>
> To gain reputation, post good
>   questions and useful answers. Your
>   peers will vote on your posts, and
>   those votes will cause you to gain
>   (or, in rare cases, lose) reputation:
>
> answer is voted up  +10
>
> question is voted up  +5
>
> answer is accepted  +15 (+2 to acceptor)
>
> post is voted down -2  (-1 to voter)
>
> A maximum of 30 votes can be cast per
>   user per day, and you can earn a
>   maximum of 200 reputation per day
>   (although accepted answers are immune
>   to this limit). Also, please note that
>   votes for any posts marked "community
>   wiki" do not generate reputation.
>
> Amass enough reputation points and
>   Stack Overflow will allow you to go
>   beyond simply asking and answering
>   questions:
>
> 15  Vote up
>
> 15  Flag offensive
>
> 50  Leave comments
>
> 100 Vote down (costs 1 rep)
>
> 100  Edit community wiki posts
>
> 200  Reduced advertising
>
> 250  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
>
> 500 Retag questions
>
> 1000  Show total up and down vote counts
>
> 1500  Create new tags
>
> 2000  Edit other people's posts
>
> 3000  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
>
> 10000  Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools